# Trying to install ubuntu desktop

Tags: system-installation, uefi

Trying to install Ubuntu on a 2013 Intel [dz87klt75k](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/70898/intel-desktop-board-dz87klt-75k.html) with

Firmware: 0458
CPU: i7-4770 CPU
RAM: 16 GB (2x8 GB)
GPU: Radeon 5870
SSD: Samsung evo 840 250gb ssd (planned on adding more after install)

After the install menu comes up and I choose install. It just restarts and goes to a black screen. Same result with Fedora and CentOS.

I am booting UEFI correctly. If I change the settings on the usb, I can at least get to a GRUB prompt but when running ls, I get file system is unknown on all the drives. Windows 10 doesn't like any of my hardware for some reason. I can get windows 7 installed with no issues.

Any and all help is appreciated. I started reading a bunch with little success.

Comment: Have you tried nomodeset? https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/925971

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you working with? Please advise. FYI, you're not the only Z87 chipset user who can't install Windows 10: https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/why-no-win10-support-for-asus-z87-boards.2459909/

Comment: i know about the common issues with z87 and win 10, its why im trying to move away from it all together. its the desktop 18.04 currently on website.

Comment: gryu, i will have to look at what that is.

Comment: i went into BIOS and disabled legacy all together and i was able to boot into a fedora live usb i had, but when i put the ubuntu usb in, it hangs at the intel screen